# Error in SQLite CREATE query

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error, create-table

A dumb question, but I can't find a error here...

```
CREATE TABLE units (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, group_id INTEGER NOT NULL, unit_name STRING NOT NULL UNIQUE (group_id, unit_name))
```

SQLite says:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: CREATE TABLE units (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, group_id INTEGER NOT NULL, unit_name STRING NOT NULL UNIQUE (group_id, unit_name))
 [ near "(": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)  [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be missing comma before `UNIQUE`:

```
CREATE TABLE units (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    group_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    unit_name STRING NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (group_id, unit_name)
)
```